# Adding Hashes from an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-hash

I am trying to create an array/hash from an array of multiple hashes with same keys and an average of values. My array:

```
[{:amount=>897500, :gross_amount=>897500, :tax=>147500, :hotel_fees=>0, :base_fare=>750000, :currency=>"INR"}, {:amount=>1006500, :gross_amount=>1006500, :tax=>156500, :hotel_fees=>0, :base_fare=>850000, :currency=>"INR"}]
```

Now I want to return something like this:

```
{:amount=>952000, :gross_amount=>952000, :tax=>152000, :hotel_fees=>0, :base_fare=>800000, :currency=>"INR"}
```

where values are the average of values from each hash with same key.

Is there a simple way to do this. I have tried using merge but currency becomes 0 with it.

My attempt:

```
p[0].merge(p[1]){|k,v1,v2| (v1+v2)/2 unless v1 && v2 == "INR"}
```

Edit:

Actually my problem didn't end here, so after getting the average I needed to insert the values inside another hash.
So I used something like this:

```
        price_array = offer_values.map do |v| 
          v.inject do |k, v| 
            k.merge!(price: k[:price].merge(v[:price]){|_, a, b| [a, b].flatten })
          end
        end
        price_array.map do |o|
          o[:price] = {}.tap{ |h| o[:price].each {|k, list| h[k] = list.all?{|e| [Fixnum, NilClass].include? e.class} ? list.map(&:to_i).sum/list.size : list.compact.first ; h  } }
        end
```

Where offer_array is the one with my orginal/first array in separate hashes. This I have tried for with 2 and 3 hashes and it is working.

If you guys have any suggestion on improving the code, It am open.

Comment: _"I have tried using merge"_ – could you show your attempt?

Comment: Merge returns this `{:amount=>952000, :gross_amount=>952000, :tax=>152000, :hotel_fees=>0, :base_fare=>800000, :currency=>nil}`

Comment: I can't have the currency nil.

Comment: My attempt: `p[0].merge(p[1]){|k,v1,v2| (v1+v2)/2 unless v1 && v2 == "INR"}`

Comment: It's a bit hard to read code in comments, you you edit your question instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two hashes in array you could use `inject` and `merge` checking if the value for the both `currency` keys are Fixnum class, if not, then take the value of currency `"INR"` in the first hash and use it:

```
array = [
  {:amount=>897500,  :gross_amount=>897500,  :tax=>147500, :hotel_fees=>0, :base_fare=>750000, :currency=>"INR"}, 
  {:amount=>1006500, :gross_amount=>1006500, :tax=>156500, :hotel_fees=>0, :base_fare=>850000, :currency=>"INR"}
]

p array.inject{|k,v| k.merge(v){|_,a,b| [a,b].all?{|e| e.is_a?(Fixnum)} ? (a+b)/2 : b}}
# => {:amount=>952000, :gross_amount=>952000, :tax=>152000, :hotel_fees=>0, :base_fare=>800000, :currency=>"INR"}
```

For two or more hashes in an array you could try with:

```
main_array = [
  {:amount=>897500,  :gross_amount=>897500,  :tax=>147500, :hotel_fees=>0, :base_fare=>750000, :currency=>"INR"}, 
  {:amount=>1006500, :gross_amount=>1006500, :tax=>156500, :hotel_fees=>0, :base_fare=>850000, :currency=>"INR"},
  {:amount=>1006500, :gross_amount=>1006500, :tax=>156500, :hotel_fees=>0, :base_fare=>850000, :currency=>"INR"},
]
array_result = main_array.flat_map(&:to_a).group_by(&:first).map do |key, array| 
  { 
    key => (
      result = array.inject(0) do |total, (_, value)| 
        value.is_a?(Fixnum) ? total + value : value
      end 
      result.is_a?(Fixnum) ? result / main_array.size : result 
    ) 
  } 
end
p array_result
```

Comment: What is `_` in `|_,a,b|` doing? Can you please explain?

Comment: @Ravi it's explained in my answer, first attribute is key, he called it _ second attribute is the old value, or value from the first hash, third attribute is the new value or value from the second hash

Comment: `_` corresponds to the hash's key, it could be named as you want, but as I'm not using it but it must be references then I assign it as `_`, that means that's something that's needed to make the block works, but won't be used inside.

Comment: The question mentions "multiple hashes", not just 2 hashes.

Answer (score 3):

Irb

```
2.2.3 :011 > b = {test1: 30, test2: 40}
 => {:test1=>30, :test2=>40} 
2.2.3 :012 > a = {test1: 20, test2: 60}
 => {:test1=>20, :test2=>60} 
2.2.3 :013 > c = a.merge(b){|key, oldval, newval| (newval + oldval)/2}
 => {:test1=>25, :test2=>50}
```

Comment: ohh I thought it was some thing else.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer will not work for more than 2 hashes, since `merge` works only 2 by 2 and you are calculating average here.

```
(((3 + 2) / 2) + 2.5) / 2 is different from (3 + 2 + 2.5) / 3
```

So I wrote a piece of code that could do what you want for whatever size of array you have

```
  def self.merge_all_and_average(array)
    new_hash = {}
    unless array.empty?
      array[0].keys.each do |key|
        if array[0][key].class == Fixnum
          total = array.map { |i| i[key] }.inject(0) { |sum, x| sum + x }
          new_hash = new_hash.merge(key => total / array.size)
        else
          new_hash = new_hash.merge(key => array[0][key])
        end
      end
    end
    new_hash
  end
```

Comment: I know it won't work for more than two hash. I just wanted an idea on how I could handle it. I was on the right path but couldn't get correct answer. My problem never was totally different and various other things were involved. This was just a part of it where I was getting confused. The solution I have used is somewhat similar to yours. Check my edit.

Answer (score 2):

This should work with any number of hashes:

```
data = [
  { amount: 897_500, gross_amount: 897_500, tax: 147_500, hotel_fees: 0, base_fare: 750_000, currency: 'INR' },
  { amount: 1_006_500, gross_amount: 1_006_500, tax: 156_500, hotel_fees: 0, base_fare: 850_000, currency: 'INR' },
  { amount: 1_006_500, gross_amount: 1_006_500, tax: 156_500, hotel_fees: 0, base_fare: 850_000, currency: 'INR' }
]

transposed_hashes = data.each_with_object(Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []}) do |h, mem|
  h.each do |k, v|
    mem[k] << v
  end
end
# {:amount=>[897500, 1006500, 1006500], :gross_amount=>[897500, 1006500, 1006500], :tax=>[147500, 156500, 156500], :hotel_fees=>[0, 0, 0], :base_fare=>[750000, 850000, 850000], :currency=>["INR", "INR", "INR"]}

average_hash = transposed_hashes.map do |k, v|
  new_value = if v[0].is_a? Integer
                v.sum.to_f / v.size
              else
                v[0]
              end
  [k, new_value]
end.to_h

puts average_hash
# {:amount=>970166.6666666666, :gross_amount=>970166.6666666666, :tax=>153500.0, :hotel_fees=>0.0, :base_fare=>816666.6666666666, :currency=>"INR"}
```

Comment: I am doing something similar as well but this method increases my complexity of the code.